# Does traffic API of Here.com works for Mumbai city?

Tags: here-api, here-traffic

https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.3/incidents.json?apiKey=tXXqLXg-i2PtCzsP2GOIwLevWMAmmKEoTWCV21UZpI8&bbox=19.18957,72.96330;19.18731,72.96387&criticality=minor

I am trying to get traffic information for India's city Mumbai, but when i execute hereapi, i get no error message but get the following output.

{"TIMESTAMP":"NA","VERSION":2.4,"TIMESTAMP2":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000","EXTENDED_COUNTRY_CODE":"NA"}

What this response means? Why i am not getting traffic information ?

Answer (score 1):

Traffic API should work for Mumbai city, but your input bounding box is very small — it contains just an intersection — so it is likely that there was no incident recorded at the time the request was sent.

Try to enlarge the bounding box, or other endpoints to get traffic information, for example [Traffic Flow within a bounding box](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/traffic/traffic-flow-bounding-box).